# Smoothness of solutions to the Burgers' Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

Consider $ u_t + uu_x =0 $ and an associated problem  $uu_t + u^2u_x=0$ ($*$).  If we let $ w= u^2$, the second PDE becomes

$$ w_t + \left(\dfrac{2}{3}w^{3/2}\right)_x=0 \>.  (**)$$

I am required to show that $u$ is a smooth solution of ($*$) with $u(x,0)=u_0(x)$ iff $w=u^2$ is a smooth solution of ($**$) with $w(x,0)=u^2(x,0)$.

I'm not quite sure where to start and would appreciate a nudge in the correct direction.

Thank you

Comment: Something's not right.  If I substitute $w = u^2$ into (**), the first term is $2 u u_t$, but the second is $(8/9) u^{1/3} u_x$.

Comment: Do you know what a smooth solution is?

Comment: @RobertIsrael yes sorry, that is the wrong exponent on $w$

Comment: @Mattos Yes, the solutions are infinitely differentiable.

Comment: Do you want solutions smooth on all of $\mathbb R^2$, or for all $t \ge 0$, or just locally?